# How to break sea-orm query using multiline statement

Tags: sea-orm

I am a beginner here using sea-orm. I am trying to break down query for filtering my data.
params are input from http query parameters. Based on value of params i want to filter data.

```
let test = ProductEntity::find();

if params.get("price_gt").is_some() {
    test.filter(product_entity::Column::Price.eq(20));
}

dbg!(test.all(&db).await?);
```

Help me[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMsgm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little late, but it can be useful for others. `Entity` uses the Build pattern. As you can see here [filter](https://docs.rs/sea-orm/latest/src/sea_orm/query/helper.rs.html#757-763) takes `mut self` as argument but also returns `self`.

In this specific case, we have to make test mutable: `let mut test = ...`, and in the if statement, we have to return ownership to the test variable:

`test = test.filter(product_entity::Column::Price.eq(20));`

Then it should work as expected.